# java sql statement version error

Tags: java, mysql

this is what i got

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQl server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by idconsumo' at line 1

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a null TableModel
```

code

```
 sSQL = "select c.idconsumo,c.idreserva,c.idproducto,p.nombre,c.cantidad,c.precio_venta "
                + ",c.estado from  consumo c inner join producto p on c.idproducto=p.idproducto"
                + " where c.idreserva = " + buscar +" order by idconsumo";
```

but still save it in the database. If i exit the app and open it again then the 
record is added

Comment: Well the SQL you've shown us is a select query, not an insert... But before anything else, you should learn about parameterized SQL. Unless `buscar` is really the name of a field, you should be using a SQL parameter to specify it.

Comment: Parameterization aside, what type is your variable `buscar` and field `c.idreserva`? If they are strings, the `buscar` value will need to be wrapped in quotes within the SQL statement itself.

Comment: Can you provide "computed" query? I am interested how this field looks like. Maybe it should have `''` if it is a string value?

Comment: buscar is a variable

Comment: is not giving the error message anymore , but is not filling the grid table

Answer (score 1):

First of all as Jon suggested, use the parametrized SQL.

You need to make few changes to the SQL as below:

```
"select c.idconsumo, c.idreserva, c.idproducto, p.nombre, c.cantidad, c.precio_venta, c.estado from  consumo c inner join producto p on c.idproducto=p.idproducto where c.idreserva = " + buscar +" order by c.idconsumo";
```

Make sure if buscar is a variable and c.idreserva is non-int column then add single quotes around it like `c.idreserva = '" + buscar +"'` and `order by c.idconsumo`

Using prepared statement:

```
String sql = "select c.idconsumo, c.idreserva, c.idproducto, p.nombre, c.cantidad, c.precio_venta, c.estado from  consumo c inner join producto p on c.idproducto=p.idproducto where c.idreserva = ? order by c.idconsumo";
PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
//if buscar is string type
prepStmt.setString(1, buscar);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Query syntax error. Please check:

```
   String sql = " select c.idconsumo,c.idreserva,c.idproducto,p.nombre,"
               +" c.cantidad,c.precio_venta, c.estado "
               +" from  consumo c inner join producto p on "
               +" c.idproducto=p.idproducto "
               +" where c.idreserva ='" + buscar +"' order by c.idconsumo ";
```

*PreparedStatement would be more accurate to use.*

A PreparedStatement is a special kind of Statement object with some useful features. Remember, you need a Statement in order to execute either a query or an update. You can use a PreparedStatement instead of a Statement and benefit from the features of the PreparedStatement.

**The PreparedStatement's primary features are:**

> Easy to insert parameters into the SQL statement. Easy to reuse the
>   PreparedStatement with new parameters. May increase performance of
>   executed statements. Enables easier batch updates.

```
       String sql = " select c.idconsumo,c.idreserva,c.idproducto,p.nombre,"
                   +" c.cantidad,c.precio_venta, c.estado "
                   +" from  consumo c inner join producto p on "
                   +" c.idproducto=p.idproducto "
                   +" where c.idreserva = ? order by c.idconsumo ";

PreparedStatement preStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
preStmt.setInt(1, buscar);
ResultSet rs = preStmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: your both codes are not consistent, in one example you are showing buscar as string and int in the next example.